# Corona Shake Event Sensitivity

Tags: events, coronasdk, shake

I created an app that shows images in an array in order when the user shakes the phone. However, the sensitivity is too bad, I really need to try hard to shake that and sometimes when I try hard, it just pass images too fast, so I can't see the first one thoroughly. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: Sorry, but you don't have any control over that in Corona. Have you tried the application on another device?

Comment: Okey, thanks for info. Nope, I haven't.

Comment: You should try that. It might be something wrong with the gyroscope on your phone.